# Visual force Rendered field help

Tags: visualforce, rerender

Hoping someone can help with the below code :

This issue im having is that when it triggers validation and prevents render from running unless all required fields have been filled in.

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Costing Enquiry Form Edit" mode="maindetail" id="pb">
         <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
         </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Customer_Name__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.OwnerId}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Contact_Name__c}" required="false"/>


             <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c}" required="true">
                 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="conditional"/>
                 <!-- triggers validation and prevents rerender from running unless all required fields have been filled in. -->
             </apex:inputField>



            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.End_User__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Target_Selling_Price__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Status__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Estimated_Quantity__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Quote_Number__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Sample_Required__c}" required="false"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Customer_is_currently_using_Seen__c}" required="true"/>

            <apex:pageBlockSection id="conditional">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.ChemCre8_Code__c}" rendered="{!IF(Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c =='Chemcre8',TRUE,FALSE)}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Bespoke_Garment_Additional_Information__c}"  rendered="{!IF(Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c =='Bespoke Garment',TRUE,FALSE)}" required="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Required_Standards_CE_Markings__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Special_Requirements_Comments__c}" required="true"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Send_to__c}" required="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>            

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" />
<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" />
<apex:relatedList list="CombinedAttachments" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you just need to use the `<apex:actionRegion>`

it would be something like

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:inputField value="{!Costing_Enquiry_Form__c.Product_Type__c}" required="true">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="conditional"/>
    </apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
```